# Suppressing/hiding/overriding Android call UI

Tags: android

Is it possible to initiate an outgoing call without having the phone invoke it's default dialing screen?  The point is to be able to make a call without someone knowing I'm making a call.

Comment: Pretty sure that's not possible...and it's also a horrible idea.

Comment: The idea was to be able to make an emergency phone call, to a parent or 911, for example, unbeknownst to those whom you'd rather not make aware of the call.  It doesn't seem particularly horrible to me.

Answer (score 1):

From an SDK application, this is not possible.